# PayPal iOS SDK nil View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I am using the most recent PayPal iOS sdk in my app.  For some unknown reason, when I try to init the PayPalPaymentViewContoller then present it, it is crashing. I have determined that the viewController is nil, but I have no idea why.

Here are the two lines of code to do with this.

The first line is the init, and the second is present

```
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment configuration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];

[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas? Let me what more information you need. I am not really sure what else to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

@linuxer have you followed [our sample code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md#sample-code)? In particular, from step 5:

> `// Check whether payment is processable.
>     if (!payment.processable) {
>       // If, for example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was empty, then
>       // this payment would not be processable. You would want to handle that here.
>     }`

If the payment is not "processable", but you go ahead anyway to create the `PayPalPaymentViewController`, then you would indeed get back `nil`.

You should also see a message to that effect in your console log. Have you taken a look there?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I had checked the console and received nothing to indicate any issues that I wasn't already aware of. Before I saw this answer, however, I had already removed all of my code and started fresh and that seemed to solve it. I must have just had something odd in there somewhere. However, I will mark this as the answer, because I am sure it had something to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object for `PayPalItem` at here in `withPrice` param, amount always be in two value after decimal. See below example:

```
PayPalItem *item1 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"T Shirt" withQuantity:1 withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:**

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",overAllTotalAmt]

**] withCurrency:@"USD" withSku:@"Hip-00037"];
```